# Spring boot serving only one request at a time

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2.7.6 with tomcat version 9.0.69

My code

```
@GetMapping("/start")
    public String demo() {
        Response output = null;
        System.out.println("Inside API");
        
        InputRequest request = new InputRequest();
        request.setType("type1");
        request.setSize(50);
        request.setPageType("page1");
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i<10000000; i++) {
            System.out.println("ankit "+i);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Inside done");
    
        return "Success";

    }
```

When I am hitting the controller multiple times using URL: **http://localhost:8000/start**, then at a time only one requesting is served.

Other requests are served when first one is completed. I got to know this from log I put.
I hit the start endpoint 10 times from 10 different browser window and output is :

```
Inside API
Inside Done
Inside API
Inside Done
Inside API
Inside Done
Inside API
Inside Done
..
```

Ideally it should be

```
Inside API
Inside API
Inside API
Inside API
...
```

What am I missing.  NO config in properties file. Using java 1.8

Comment: Your for loop is causing excessive cpu usage, leading to contention. Instead of a for loop try a `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Same with Thread.sleep, serving one request at a time

Comment: Also make sure you are really using standalone browsers and not just windows as that will queue requests from the client to the server. You are probably better of testing this from the command line using something like curl or httpie.

Comment: Checked from terminal also, same output

Comment: You are either doing it wrong or you have really messed up your configuration. Either way without further information I think we can conclude we cannot answer your question.

Comment: What further information you like to ask. I havd shared the versions I used. Nothing in properties file.

Comment: Share the project so that we can have a look. You only have a controller that isn't something we can run. If I run a test I get multiple tests, so either you are testing wrong (not using multiple threads/different calls) or you are messing things up in your configuration properties or java.